# Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datedelta'

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to calculate a time period length, but as one date is a `timedelta` and the other is a `datedelta`, this error is thrown:

`Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datedelta'`

Code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datedelta import datedelta
import math

step_period = datedelta(months=1)
to_from = timedelta(weeks=6)
number_of_steps = math.ceil((to_from) / step_period)
```

NB: `datedelta` is a Python library: it can be obtained wih `sudo pip3 install datedelta`

Possible input:

My length of time to consider is 6 weeks (`to_from`), I wish to divide it into chunks (`number_of_steps`) of 1 month (`step_period`). How many divisions will there be?

Expected output:
`number_of_steps = 2`

How can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The `number_of_steps` should be an even division of the `to_from` date in lengths of `step_period`. For example, the length of time considered here is 3 days, but they should be divided into chunks of one month (I know this isn't possible, I just plugged random values in for test purposes)

Comment: Please update your question with some sample input and output data.

Comment: A mathematically sound example would be a period of 3 days, and a length of time = 1 month, number of steps would then be equal to ten

Comment: Please update your question with some sample input and output data.

Comment: I can't run any of your code. What is `datedelta`?

Comment: `datedelta` is a similar library to `timedelta` that allows for longer periods like months and years, you can get it with `sudo pip3 install datedelta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert to the same units and then do a division:
(having installed `datedelta` package)

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datedelta import datedelta
import math

def delta_to_days(delta):
    return delta.days + delta.months * 30

step_period = datedelta(months=1)
to_from = timedelta(days=3)
number_of_steps = math.ceil(delta_to_days(step_period) / to_from.days )
print(number_of_steps)
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: Almost... it's just sort of backwards, but I can use your answer to make a working example: you switched the values on the division
`(to_from.days) / delta_to_days(step_period)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure timedelta won't allow for months= as an input. I also could not find this datedelta you have. Instead I could replicate your answer as per:

```
In: math.ceil(timedelta(weeks=6)/timedelta(weeks=4))
Out: 2
```

Comment: This works on this example, but this project will be scaled up to years over time, and it isn't efficient to count weeks (highest division of `timedelta`). `datedelta` is a similar library that allows for longer periods like months and years, you can get it with `sudo pip3 install datedelta`

Comment: Why can you not just make your to_from = datedelta(weeks=6)?

Comment: weeks aren't included in `datedelta`, this error is thrown: `got an unexpected keyword argument 'weeks'`

Comment: Ah I see, I guess you could just use the days in the datedelta function if you always want to split into 1 month, otherwise creating some conversion function like quamrana is probably your best bet.